# Conditional coloring in bokeh vbar plots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

Try to make a vbar plot with bokeh. Would like to set a condition for the fill color when the value exceeds a pre-set number. Say, red when greater than 5, else purple. Is this doable with bokeh?

Any demonstration would be greatly appreciated. My data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a column in your DataFrame named `color` and pass this data to the keyword `color` in the function [`vbar()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html?highlight=vbar#bokeh.plotting.Figure.vbar) using the DataFrame as `source`.

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df['color'] = np.where(df['a'].le(5), 'purple','red')

p = figure()
p.vbar('index', top='a', width=0.75, fill_alpha=0.5, color='color', source=df)
show(p)
```

**Output**

[image: bar plot]

Comment: Great! Thanks. I could use this concept for the fill alpha as well? Also my data file is huge. How much would this slow down the speed of the calculation?

Comment: Yes, this basically works for all keywords `bokeh` offers. A quick test for the run time shows that the difference isn't huge. The plain figure without color and alpha keywords needs about 6ms to calculate. With both values it takes 6.4ms. Then you have to display it, which takes some time, but in general there is no problem to add this to the figure.